# jQuery validation select not equal to

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery empty form</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="js/validate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" id="testform" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Osobní údaje:</legend>
                <label for="firstname">Jméno:</label>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" /><br />
                <label for="surname">Příjmení:</label>
                <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" /><br />
                <label for="gender">Pohlaví:</label>
                <select form="testform" id="gender" name="gender">
                    <option select="selected" value="select">Vyberte pohlaví</option>
                    <option value="man">Muž</option>
                    <option value="woman">Žena</option>
                </select><br />
                <input id="confirm" name="confirm" type="submit" value="Potvrdit" />
            </fieldset>
            <div id="errors">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then following jQuery validation script

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo", function(element, value, param){
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testform").validate({
        onkeyup: function(element){$(element).valid()},
        onfocusout: false,
        errorLabelContainer: "#errors",
        wraper: "li",
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                minlength: 3,
                required: true
            },
            surname: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            gender: {
                required: true,
                notEqualTo: "select"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Zadejte své jméno<br />",
                minlength: "Jméno musí mít délku alespoň 3 znaky<br />"
            },
            surname: {
                required: "Zadejte své příjmení<br />",
                minlength: "Příjmení musí mít délku alespoň 2 znaky<br />"
            },
            gender: {
                notEqualTo: "Zvolte pohlaví<br />"
            }
        },
    });
});
```

I tried to do my first own jQuery method notEqualTo. But it doesn't work. I'd like to do that if the user has chosen option with value select, it means that he / she doesn't choose a gender. And if it's that situation the error message should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just dont give any value in select="selected" option and add "required" in the end of select.

```
<select form="testform" id="gender" name="gender" required>
    <option select="selected" value="">Vyberte pohlaví</option>
    <option value="man">Muž</option>
    <option value="woman">Žena</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried also your advice and still no error message.

Answer (score 0):

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/sugoferave/edit?html,js,output)

You must change the  `Parameter` .. `function(element, value, param)` to `function(value, element, param)` . that's it.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo", function(value, element, param){
        return this.optional(element) || value != param;
    });
```

**WITH MESSAGE**

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo", function(value, element, param){
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
},"This field is required");
```

If you want more customize the message  read  about `jquery-validation`

```js
$.validator.addMethod("notEqualTo", function(value, element, param){
    return this.optional(element) || value != param;
},'this Field is Required');
 $.validator.setDefaults({
        success: "valid"
    });
    $("#testform").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                minlength: 3,
                required: true
            },
            surname: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            gender: {
                required: true,
                notEqualTo: function(){return $('#gender').val()}
            }
        },
      messages:{
        gender:{
        notEqualTo : "Custom Error"
        }
      
      }
    });
$('button').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#testform").valid();

})
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  
<body>
  <form  id="testform" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Osobní údaje:</legend>
                <label for="firstname">FIRSTNAME:</label>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" /><br />
                <label for="surname">SURNAME:</label>
                <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" /><br />
                <label for="gender">GENDER:</label>
                <select form="testform" id="gender" name="gender">
                    <option select="selected" value="select">SELECT</option>
                    <option value="man">MAN</option>
                    <option value="woman">WOMEN</option>
                </select><br />
              <button id="confirm" name="confirm" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">SUBMIT</button>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="errors">
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this and the same result. No error message.

Comment: Check the link  and i will updated the answer also. @MichalVlasák

Comment: No, I want to display a message that is written under messages notEqualTo. It says Choose a gender. It means, that if the value selected is choosen I'd like to display this message. It is not important to me, that the field is required. Important is, that the user didn't choose the gender.

Comment: ya.. `this field is required` is the default error for your  `element`. if you want custom message put on `validate` method @MichalVlasák